How to access JS variables defined in a QtWebEnginePage.runJavaScript call from the HTML document <script> tag?
I'm trying to add to a PyQt5 application a QtWebEngineView widget. This widget must load the following very simple SVG:
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" />
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
        alert("bar")
        mynamespace.myfunction();
    ]]></script>
</svg>

But obviously, I need to define mynamespace beforehand, so I'm trying the following in my widget constructor:
class MyWebPageView(QtWebEngineView):

    def __init__(svg,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        
        self.page().runJavaScript(
            """
            alert("foo");
            const mynamespace = { myfunction: function() { alert("success");}};
            """)
        time.sleep(3) #to be sure this is not a timing issue
        self.load(QUrl("file:///path/to/svg.svg"))

I see the "foo" alert, then the "bar" alert. The red circle is properly drawn, but the "success" alert never shows, and I get the following error message:
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: mynamespace is not defined

What have I done wrong?

When you load a new url the js namespace is cleared. You can just test it in a browser console: declare a variable, then open the svg from the address bar and the variable doesn't exist anymore. There may be solutions for this, but you should first clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Ha, of course... My issue is that I have to load SVGs that I'm not responsible for, and that are used initially in a context where some JS has already been loaded. I'm trying to emulate this JS loading, because by specs I cannot modify the SVGs themselves.

You need to employ user-script injection. See: QWebEngineScript.

I tried that, but even with InjectionPoint.DocumentCreation, the QWebEngineScript code is called after the JS embedded in the SVG, thus generating the same error message.

I wrote a new question regarding this QWebEngineScript issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79064907
