How to ensure QWebEngineScript is executed before any other JS script in HTML document?
I'm trying to add to a PyQt5 application a QtWebEngineView widget. This widget must load the following very simple SVG (which, by specs, I cannot modify):
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" />
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
        alert("tag")
        mynamespace.myfunction();
    ]]></script>
</svg>

But obviously, I need to define mynamespace.myfunction beforehand, so I'm trying the following in my widget constructor:
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineScript


class MyWebPageView(QtWebEngineView):

    def __init__(svg,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        # Create script object
        js_script = QWebEngineScript()
        js_script.setSourceCode(
            """
                alert("qwebenginescript");
                const mynamespace = { myfunction: function() { alert("success");}};
            """
        )
        js_script.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript.DocumentCreation)
        
        # Add the script to the page
        self.page().scripts().insert(js_script)

        time.sleep(3) #to be sure this is not a timing issue
        
        # Load the SVG into the page
        self.load(QUrl("file:///path/to/svg.svg"))

I expect the QWebEngineScript to be executed before the SVG's <script> code, but what I see is first the the "tag" alert, and only then the "qwebenginescript" alert. The red circle is properly drawn, but the "success" alert never shows, and I get the following error message:
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: mynamespace is not defined

How can I ensure the QWebEngineScript is really executed first?
(Note: this is a follow-up of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79059688)

It looks like some kind of bug or limitation in chrome. For some reason, it treats html and xml mime-types differently. A plain html document with a script block works as expected, but adding xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" causes the injected script to load last. A hackish work-around is to do this: self.setContent(open('path/to/my.svg', 'rb').read(), 'text/html'). This works for me with your svg file (I suppose because svg can be embedded in plain html), but I doubt it will work with all possible xhtml content.

Unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work for me  I'll parse the SVG to add a 
You should also add this line: js_script.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript.ScriptWorldId.MainWorld). And to be clear, you must also remove the self.load(...) line (and the time.sleep, for that matter, as it's totally pointless).

I did not add the setWorldId because I thought MainWorld was the default. This was the issue. The fix you suggested now works perfectly.
